# Add one day to a model's data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to Razor and I want to know how to add one day to model's date object. I need to put a "next day" link

Here is the view code

```
<a href="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.date)">Next Day</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried model.date.AddDays(1), that is if the type is DateTime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass the `NextDay` as a `DateTime` in the `Model` as well using `DateTime.AddDays()` method.
This method returns a new `DateTime` that adds the specified number of days to the value of this instance.

```
model.NextDay = startDate.AddDays(1);
```

then use that property in your `DisplayNameFor`:

```
<a href="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NextDay)">Next Day</a>
```

There is a little paragraph about it on `MSDN`

> This method does not change the value of this DateTime. Instead, it returns a new DateTime whose value is the result of this operation.

Answer (score 3):

You generally don't want to "calculate" values in your view - that's the model's responsibility.  The cleanest way is to add a property to your model that calculates the next date:

```
public DateTime NextDay 
{
    get {return this.date.AddDays(1); }
}
```

then use that property in your `DisplayNameFor`:

```
<a href="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NextDay)">Next Day</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `model.date` a `DateTime`? If so then use [`DateTime.AddDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx). It might not be worth adding a special property to your model just for this.

Also, are you sure that your date is going to be serialized in a format your server will understand? I would recommend ensuring you specify a particular format for dates to be used in Urls, such as `yyyy-MM-dd`, using the [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method of the `DateTime` object. This way any changes to your server locale will not impact your site.

```html
<a href='@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))'>Previous Day</a>
<a href='@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))'>Next Day</a>
```