# Razor Foreach SQL data by date

Tags: sql, razor, foreach

this might be an easy problem to solve, or not, but it's hard to explain and put into google so I couldn't find a solution.

In my database I have multiple rows and column with different data and a few have the same date, so I want to do a foreach loop that reads all the data from a single date, sums that all up and puts it into a variable, (this part I know how to do), but after all this is done in one loop, on the next loop around I want it to be the next day.

I'm wondering if this is possible? I guess you could do a `i++` kind of thing but that wouldn't work when going from the 31st to 1st the next month I guess.

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Comment: startDate.AddDays(1) ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030575/add-one-day-to-a-models-data

Comment: Cool! That seems to be the right thing! Just need to figure out how to use it haha! Thanks for the help!